# Create alternative \textdiscount

Tags: symbols, characters, textcomp

My purpose is to create `\textdiscount` using **/** and `\cdot` or **.**(dot). Can you help me?

======================================

After from Christian Hupfer's Solution

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with `\textdiscount`?

Comment: The format is too dense. It looks bad on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a 'proper' combination of `\kern` and `\raisebox` with `em` and `ex` units that scale accordingly to the currently applied fontsize.

The kerning of `-0.2em` will shrink the horizontal distance of `.` and `/` and the `\raisebox` will raise or lower the `.` according to the value. Use `ex` for vertical raising and `em` for horizontal shifts.

Adjust the values for best personal tastes -- the given values are just 'arbitrary' ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\newcommand{\textdis}{\raisebox{1.2ex}{.}\kern-0.2em/\kern-0.2em\raisebox{-0.5ex}{.}}

\begin{document}


\textdis

{\large \textdis}

{\Large \textdis}

{\LARGE \textdis}

{\huge \textdis}

{\Huge \textdis}

Normal \textdiscount

And now bold:

\bfseries

\textdis

{\large \textdis}

{\Large \textdis}

{\LARGE \textdis}

{\huge \textdis}

{\Huge \textdis}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textdis` means *Please turn the page* in Turkish. I also want to say hello again.

Comment: @Özgür: Do you mean the symbol % has the meaning of 'turn the page' in Turkish?

Comment: No, percentage symbol in Turkish is the percent symbol. This means that you only need to 'turn the page' of the new sign that comes from the dots and /. I hope I can express it correctly. I've added a picture.

Comment: @Özgur: I just used % since I was too lazy to look the unicode for `\textdiscount` up